# iPhone development on the new MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, development

I want to do iPhone development with the [MacBook](http://www.apple.com/macbook/). The MacBook only has one USB-C port, so I may need [a USB-C adaptor](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) to load my apps on my iPhone.

Is the USB-C adaptor necessary to load freshly compiled iOS apps on my iPhone?

Comment: I've edited the side questions out of this to keep it focused. If Randomblue could elaborate on why you feel a connection to an iPhone is needed for development, we might be able to offer better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Developing on the new MacBook (Early 2015) isn't going to be any harder than using any recent portable:

1. Use the simulator (this can be great at first, but you'll need to test on a real device later).
2. Build an **IPA** and upload it through iTunes (works over wifi) or [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) (works over cellular too). Both options would be really slow, but they can work combined with the simulator. There's no debugger though.
3. Use Apple's $19 adapter and add a USB hub if you need more than one device connected.

Answer (score 8):

You really need to make up your mind whether you want the latest and shiniest product, or whether you want a good development machine. Once you use Interface Builder, a 15" MBP is the smallest that is usable without an external monitor. And once you use an external monitor, you are connected to a desk, and the portability doesn't help much.

The new MacBook is targeted at certain use cases. Serious software development isn't one of them.

Comment: I agree with this statement - especially the part about thinking what you really need. If you don't have an iMac or Mac Pro for desktop use, there are parts of development where CPU speed can slow things down. However, connecting a second or third display (or iPad using an app like Duet) will make screen size irrelevant. Also, the MacBook and a Mac Mini running Xcode server to offload builds might be a very nice setup for many developers. I get very good results from the mid line 2012 retina MBP and better, so the new MacBook is clearly in that class so for me it would be just fine.

Answer (score 7):

> I want to do iPhone development with the MacBook.

No, you don't. Really, you don't.

That model is meant for users who value portability over *everything* else. Developing an iOS application (or, really, any other software product) requires many, many hours at the keyboard. You need screen space for editors, the editor's toolbars, the documentation you will refer to twice a minute, and the simulator to test the results of your labour. You don't do this during spare moments here and there.

iOS code also needs to be compiled - not a process for lightweight, energy-efficient systems. The MacBook isn't for video editing either, Apple has other models for this part of the market.

I do software development with a 27 inch desktop, and it's about the right size. I also have an Air for remote work, but it uses my desktop for the heavy lifting and content delivery. My work would take substantially longer on a 13 inch screen.

Answer (score 4):

You will need the [USB-C to USB Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter) for this:

> The USB-C to USB Adapter lets you connect iOS devices and many of your standard USB accessories to a MacBook with USB-C port.
>
> Plug the USB-C end of the adapter into the USB-C port on your MacBook, and then connect your flash drive, camera, or other standard USB device. You can also connect a USB cable to sync and charge your iPhone, iPad, or iPod.

Comment: Your quote shows that you *can* use the adapter, but not that you *should* use the adapter (i.e. that it is necessary).

Comment: That's always a problem when a question actually contains several questions at once :-) It might be better to ask a new question on whether a wired connection is mandatory for iOS development (AFAIK the answer is yes, but I don't have a reference for this).

Comment: Hold on. My original question *includes a solution*. (See the link to a different adapter.) And I quote "Is the USB-C adaptor *necessary*?"

Comment: @Randomblue You don't even need an iOS device to develop. It just speeds up certain parts of the development cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone is jailbroken, you can use this script found on the [iPhone Dev Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode) to upload your application via SSH. You'll need to set up SSH key pairs, and add this script as a Run Script Build Phase.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Modify this to your device's IP address.
IP="192.168.1.109"

# Verify that the build is for iOS Device and not a Simulator.

if [[ "$NATIVE_ARCH" != "i386" && "$NATIVE_ARCH" != "x86_64" ]]; then
# Kill any running instances and remove the app folder.
ssh root@$IP "killall ${TARGETNAME}; rm -rf /Applications/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
# Self sign the build.
ldid -S $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/${WRAPPER_NAME}/$TARGETNAME
# Copy it over.
scp -r $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/${WRAPPER_NAME} root@$IP:/Applications/
ssh root@$IP "su -c uicache mobile"

# This part just creates create an OS X notification to let you know that the process is done.
# You can get terminal-notifier from https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier.
# You can remove this line if you want.
/Applications/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier -title "Build Complete" -message "${WRAPPER_NAME} installed on ${IP}"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I most definitely would not use the new MacBook for iOS development. The screen is too small, the hard disk is too small, the RAM is barely enough. And to add insult to injury, you have to buy a dongle in order to get access to more than one port. No thanks!

Get a refurb 13-inch or 15-inch MacBook Pro (perhaps with Retina display), max out the RAM (from a third party like Crucial or Kingston), and pair it with a 27-inch external monitor. That's a much better setup for what you want to do.